# Remove lines recursively from a SQL TEXT column

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Text column which has a block of text and has multiple lines which are not relevant and I need to remove only those lines. 
Example - This is all one column value:

```
Header_ID askdjfhklasjdhfklajhfwoi fhweiohrognfk
ABC
SECTION_ID asdfhkwjehfi efjhewiu1382204 3904834
123
SECTION_ID deihefgjkahf dfjsdhfkl edfashldfkljh
```

So basically I need to remove all lines which are starting with Header_ID and Section_ID and the output Text i need is just

```
ABC
123
```

The only thing constant about these lines is the first word it starts with and depending on that I need to remove the whole line.

Comment: If they are stored in multiple lines there will be a char(13) or something. You can use this to split it into several lines.

Comment: sql-server. Tag added. Thanks

Comment: What's the sql-server version, and is the column defined as NTEXT?

Comment: I tried what @otto sent and that worked. Just need to work on optimizing it for a large chunk. Thanks guys.

Comment: @DeanOC this is on SQL server 2016 and the column is of DataType Image, I am converting to varbinary and then to varchar to play with the textual data in it.

Comment: When you've got it working, please post your solution as an answer, and self-accept it. That way, you can help future readers who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using SQL Server 2016 and not 2017 what i did to resolve the issue was First break all the data into multiple rows(Cross apply with the Split function) using the delimiter as CHAR(13) and then taking only rows that did not start with Header_ID, Section_ID etc and using stuff again built the text block. 
Thanks again @otto for the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. Details about how it works are below. Note this solution needs **MSSQL 2017+** to work.

```
-- Place the raw string value as varchar data in a variable so it is convenient to work with:

declare @rawValue varchar(max) = 'Header_ID askdjfhklasjdhfklajhfwoi fhweiohrognfk
ABC
SECTION_ID asdfhkwjehfi efjhewiu1382204 3904834
123
SECTION_ID deihefgjkahf dfjsdhfkl edfashldfkljh';

-- Perform multiple operations on the raw value and save the result to another variable:

declare @convertedValue varchar(max) = 
(
    select string_agg(value, char(13) + char(10)) 
    from string_split(@rawValue, char(10)) 
    where value not like 'header_id%' and value not like 'section_id%'
);

-- Display converted value.
select @convertedValue;
```

The magic begins with the `string_split()` function which produces a table value. It detects the line feed character, `char(10)`, and splits the multi-line string into a table with each line from the string in a separate row.

Next, we filter out the rows from the table that we don't want. These rows begin with the known substrings `header_id` and `section_id`. This is accomplished in the `where` clause.

Lastly, for the output, we use `string_agg()` and aggregate the remaining rows (the lines we do want) back into a string with the individual values delimited by a combination of the carriage return `char(13)` and line feed `char(10)` characters.

Comment: My only reservation about this is that MSSQL is very picky about newline characters. In order to get this example to work, I am splitting using only the line feed `char(10)` character. But then I am re-assembling (aggregating) using both the carriage return and line feed characters `char(13) + char(10)`. So it is possible that a stray carriage return is left in the data, which may cause problems later if the data is exported to another layer in the stack like HLL. If so, some additional scrubbing may be required.